# Observable collection of item do not trigger Converter

Tags: c#, xaml, binding, observablecollection, converters

I have a xaml like this (i removed useless lines)

```
<Window x:Class="LaRenouvellerieUpdater.MainWindow"
    xmlns:converters="clr-namespace:LaRenouvellerieUpdater.Converters">
<Window.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <viewmodel:DataViewModel x:Key="DataViewModel"/>
        <model:PhotosModel x:Key="PhotosModel"/>
        <converters:UriToCachedImageConverter x:Key="UriToCachedImageConverter"/>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <TabControl>
        <TabItem Header="Posts instagrams">
            <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding InstagramsPhotos, Mode=TwoWay}" 
                      DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource DataViewModel}}">
                <DataGrid.Columns>
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Url" Width="*" MaxWidth="150">
                        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <Image>
                                    <Image.Source>
                                        <BitmapImage UriSource="{Binding Path=Url, Converter={StaticResource UriToCachedImageConverter}, Mode=TwoWay}" DecodePixelWidth="150" />
                                    </Image.Source>
                                </Image>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
```

And an observable collection like this :

```
        private ObservableCollection<PhotosModel> _instagramsPhotos = new ObservableCollection<PhotosModel>();
    public ObservableCollection<PhotosModel> InstagramsPhotos
    {
        get => _instagramsPhotos;
        set
        {
            _instagramsPhotos = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged();
        }
    }
```

A PhotoModel like this :

```
        public PhotosModel(Action<object, PropertyChangedEventArgs> photosModel_PropertyChanged)
    {
        PropertyChanged = new PropertyChangedEventHandler(photosModel_PropertyChanged);
    }

    private void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string name = "") => 
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
    private string _url;
    public string Url
    {
        get => _url;
        set
        {
            _url = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("Url");
        }
    }
```

And my Converter UriToCachedImage never triggers at start when i'm pushing element in my observablecollection. I don't know why.
I tried to pass my observable collection to all PhotosModel for triggering it if attributes are modified but doesn't work.

Thanks

Comment: Passing event handler into the model and assigning it with `=` looks weird. Without proper [mcve] hard to tell more. Somewhere notification is missing, so converter is not running.

Comment: Are you assigning `InstagramsPhotos` to a new object or using Add method to add the items in it?

Comment: With this, the PropertyEvent is passing BEFORE the Url setting so the notification fires correctly. When i create a new PhotosModel it fires RaisePropertyChanged("InstagramPhotos")

Answer (score 0):

I resolve this issue by create an attribute in my class that do the converter's job. That's not exactly what i would but it works.